# Magento: multidomain sitemap url getting 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have multidomain magento site.

```
 main store is  http://xxz.com   second store is  http://abbc.com
```

i have generated sitemap for each store view.  for xxz.com site map url is

```
 http://xxz.com/sitemap_xxz/sitemap.xml
```

for second storeview type url is:

```
 http://abbc.com/sitemap_abBc/sitemap.xml
```

unfortunately Second sitemap url returning 404 not found.

while the folder and files are already there.

```
 how to fix multidomain sitemap issue?
```

Answer (score 1):

The sitemap is created directly in the main store then you must create a link file in **abbc.com** pointing to **xxz.com**

***Assuming that the shops are located on the same server***, you need to use SSH to do this:

```
cd abbc.com
ln -s /home/xxz.com/sitemap/ sitemap
```

*Note that you must specify the full path to the sitemap, remember that this is just an example*